Could a Lenovo T14s's 20s0 USB ports be shut off by Microsoft ACPI compliant battery control method?
After thoroughly researching the issue with my friend's Lenovo T14s 20s0, it appears there may be some kind of protection in place that has stopped all power input to any of the USB ports.
I read that the dock he's been using with the device has caused power issues occur on the AMD version (mines not) for another user on the Toshiba Support boards, and I have read the USB ports not working being a common problem with this model a repair requiring major replacements. However, I saw this video on YouTube but I do not have the knowledge necessary to provide power to the battery or the computer directly to attempt the steps in the video. My question is 2 parts:
Is the ACPI control method capable of causing the usb ports to deactivate? If so, how can I provide power to this computer, or the battery, long enough to get it turned on?
Heres the links:

Fix: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vljWubmo1U4
T14 charging issue: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T-series-Laptops/Lenovo-Thinkpad-T14-Gen-1-Charging-Problem/m-p/5271164?page=1#6178448
Dock: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T-series-Laptops/T14-P14s-Gen-1-AMD-issue-with-USB-C-dockingstation-Gen-1/m-p/5101970?page=1#5445335


“Is the ACPI control method capable of causing the usb ports to deactivate?” - No; Windows cannot control the ports if the system is turned off. Your device not changing is caused by some unidentified issue. Your second link suggests it could be caused by a fault in the circuit responsible for charging the device. Do you actually have the same dock as described in the third link?

"Power saving" ON, for USB ports?

It is exceptionally difficult to diagnose hardware issues remotely. While your efforts are to be lauded, an open forum where ongoing discussion, with interrelated questions being discussed and answered in an ongoing way may be better suited to supporting your efforts here, rather than the more structured QA format we hold to here on Superuser.
